# vs code consistent keybindings for Mac and windows with settings sync

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding, platform-independence

I use a windows computer for work and have painstakingly set up many keybindings for common tasks, as well as many other personalizations I really would like to have transferred to my personal computer, which is a Mac.

I recently found out about and set up [Settings Sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync), which is pretty awesome, but I can't seem to get my keybindings to work quite how I would like.

First, it doesn't seem that any of my keybindings transferred--when I open up the keyboard shortcuts on Mac and display User Keybindings, the list is empty, yet when I do this on Windows, all my keybindings are there.

To complicate matters, I sometimes use a Windows keyboard with my Mac. Without getting into too much detail, I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish with a particular shortcut:

On windows machine, I use the right `alt` and `ctrl` keys to open up my integrated terminal with:

`alt+ctrl+t`

I'd like to keep this keybinding to work even when on my Mac because when I use my windows keyboard with it, I still have the `alt` and `ctrl` keys on the right side of the keyboard.

However, on my Mac without the windows keyboard, in place of the `alt` and `ctrl` keys I have the `cmd` and `option` keys, so in this instance I'd like `cmd+option+t` to trigger the integrated terminal.

So, is my solution to simply recreate all my windows shortcuts that use `alt+ctrl` with a corresponding `cmd+opt` version for Mac? And what about all the missing user keybindings that didn't seem to transfer with settings sync (logs show that they should've been transferred)? If anyone has any advice about how to properly set this up, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Settings Sync synchronizes the user’s shortcuts by platform, which would prevent conflicts between Windows and Mac. So to achieve what you’re looking for, it should be enough to properly configure your shortcuts as you want them to be now in Mac.

There shouldn’t be any conflict when you move to your Windows machine, each platform should keep its own configuration :)